# "We hope" versus "We will hope"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

Is there a difference between "we hope" and " we will hope"?

I read in "The Adventure of the Mazarin Stone" by Sir. Arthur Conan Doyle:

"'And Mr Holmes knows it?'

'Mr Holmes always knows whatever there is to know.'

'Well, we'll hope he won't fail and that Lord Cantlemere will be confounded. But I say, Billy, what is that curtain for across the window?'"

Comment: It's the equivalent of saying 'Let's hope that...', suggesting that hope would be the best attitude to take in the present situation.

Answer (score -1):

There's the difference in the form and meaning.
'We hope' - the Present Simple Tense which is used for permanent actions and states (for example,  always, regularly, sometimes, etc.).
'We will hope' - the Future Simple Tense  which is used for future actions and states, as well as such actions as wishes, personal predictions, promises, instant decisions, threats, etc.

Comment: ...which would mean you don't wish it yet but will wish it in the future.